# How to coerce data type of a large matrix to another similar matrices in R

Tags: r

I have n matrices with same number of columns but different data types. I want to coerce all the matrices to a particular matrix data type so that I can `rbind` all of them.

**Input**

```
  mat1 <- data.frame(var1=rep(2010,10), var2=letters[1:10], var3 = as.factor(rep(NA,10)))
  mat2 <- data.frame(var1=rep(2010,10), var2=letters[1:10], var3 = as.numeric(rep(1,10)))

  mat3 <- ...
```

I want to coerce like this `data type of mat1 <- data type of mat2` to `rbind(mat1,mat2)` without warning/error. Since my matrices are very large so it's not possible to change each variable data type separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by not being able to "change each variable data type separately," you may be able to use `mapply` with `as`:

```
mat1[] <- mapply(FUN = as, mat2, sapply(mat2, class), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: It also changes var3 of mat1 to numeric 1. I don't want to change the value string.